# How to determine has Component active LoadMask or not?

Tags: extjs

I have a window and a form inside which is putting LoadMask on its submit. While submitting process I catch `ESC` key pressing on window not to allow user to close it during form submit.

How to determine has form active LoadMask or not?

Maybe something like stores `isLoading()` method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you mask `Element` (for example `grid.getEl().mask()`) then there is such method: `grid.getEl().isMasked()`. 
If you use `LoadMask` then try this:

```
var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(grid, {msg:"Please wait..."});
myMask.show();

Ext.ComponentMgr.each(function(i, value){
    if ((value instanceof Ext.LoadMask) && value.isVisible() && 
        (value.ownerCt === panel || value.floatParent == panel))
    {
        alert('masked');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/Hsy5c/8/